# Vue.js show and hide the navbar on different pages of the routing

Tags: routes, vuejs3, navbar

This is my App.vue template. I want to show the `<Sidebar>`when a variable called `'auth'` from the `localStorage` is true, because if the `'auth'` is false, I am at the `Login` page and don't need the `Sidebar`. I have declared the function `checkAuthStatus` in the `computed:` section.

`App.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="page">
    <div v-show="checkAuthStatus" class="logobar">
      <p>This is the logobar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_content">
      <Sidebar v-show="checkAuthStatus" />
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    checkAuthStatus() {
      if (localStorage.getItem('auth') === 'true') return true
      else return false
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

`Login.vue`

In the Login page I have a Login button with the following `@click.prevent` function.

```html
<template>
  <form action="">
    <div class="field">
      <lable class="font-color-blue">E-mail</lable>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="field">
      <lable class="font-color-blue">Password</lable>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="center">
      <button id="login" class="button" @click.prevent="login">Login</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    login() {
      localStorage.setItem('auth', 'true')
      this.$router.push('/orders')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

It brings me to the `'/orders/'` link, but the Sidebar does not show up until I manually refresh the page. I tried with `this.$router.go('/orders');` and `this.$nextTick(() => this.$router.push('/orders'));`. I also tried `v-show` and `v-if`, but nothing works. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What is the code of `checkAuthStatus`? Do you have the proper dependencies there?

Comment: It is just an if-statement, that retruns true or false, based on the value of the 'auth' variable in localStorage. And it works correctly, because the sidebar shows up after I refresh the page.

Comment: You are not supposed to refresh the page anyway, so you can forget about that "solution" anyway. What do you see in your Vue devtools for the computed state? The proper value? Can you please edit your snippet with all of the relevant code? Or provide us with a [repro]?

Comment: Do you need some code from the Sidebar?

Comment: Should be okay IMO. What do you see in your Vue devtools? Proper state + localStorage?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to see that.

Comment: Go there: https://devtools.vuejs.org/ Open it on your project and inspect the component with the state that you want to double check or anything that looks false.

Comment: I installed the extension, but I don't find where the localStorage or the computed state is.

Comment: localStorage is in your regular browser devtools (in the `Application` tab). As for the computed state, it's on the given component. Select it with the Vue devtools and you will be able to find out where it is.

Comment: localStorage gets updated to true when I click the login button. I still don't find the state, sorry.

Comment: I think the problem could be that the sidebar is in the App.vue and not in the routes. And once the App loads, it only changes the <router-view>. But does it make sense to include the Sidebar in every page that I need it in?

Comment: Looking at the Vue devtools, it looks like the localStorage is not reactive. A good approach would be to use [this composable](https://vueuse.org/core/useLocalStorage/) or something old school with Vue2 and some state.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with an `$emit` in the Login page that is bound to the `login()` method in the App.vue

`App.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="page">
    <div v-show="isLoggedIn" class="logobar">
      <p>This is the logobar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_content">
      <Sidebar v-show="isLoggedIn" />
      <router-view @login="login"></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    isLoggedIn: false
  }
  methods: {
    login() {
      this.isLoggedIn= true;
      localStorage.setItem('auth', 'true');
    },
  },
}
</script>
```