# Sharing reactive localStorage state between multiple vue apps on the same page

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, toggle, sidebar

I'm creating a dashboard with Laravel and VueJS, I created a button that allows to enlarge or reduce my sidebar in a `Sidebar.vue` component here is my components:

```html
<template>
  <aside :class="`${is_expanded ? 'is-expanded' : ''}`">
    <div class="head-aside">
      <div class="app-logo">
        <i class="bx bxl-trip-advisor"></i>
      </div>
      <span class="app-name">CONTROLPANEL</span>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-toggle-wrap">
      <button class="menu-toggle" @click="ToggleMenu()">
        <span class="boxicons"><i class="bx bx-chevrons-right"></i></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </aside>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      is_expanded: ref(localStorage.getItem('is_expanded') === 'true'),
    }
  },

  methods: {
    ToggleMenu() {
      this.is_expanded = !this.is_expanded
      localStorage.setItem('is_expanded', this.is_expanded)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

The problem that arises is that in another component I created a navbar with a fixed width, what I would like to do is that when my sidebar changes size I would like my navbar to also change, in the other component I just have a template with a nav and the import of my sidebar.

Comment: `ref` is for Composition API, if you use Options API with `data`, `methods` etc, you don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you are using laravel with vue. It's not clear how the vue components are integrated, but I'm going to assume that laravel injects individual vue components that you would like to communicate. (as opposed to a vue based SPA that communicates with laravel using API only)

The two components are not aware of each other. Even though they both have access to the same localStorage, they don't know when the values there are updated.

There are several ways you can deal with this, here's one way

create a reactive object outside of the components to manage the shared state

```js
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
const isExpandedRef = ref(localStorage.getItem('is_expanded') === 'true');

window.IS_EXPANDED = computed({
  get(){
    return isExpandedRef.value
  },
  set(value){
    isExpandedRef.value = !!value;
    localStorage.setItem('is_expanded', isExpandedRef.value);
  }
})
```

the `ref` is required so that when `isExpandedRef.value` changes, the computed getter triggers notifications to it's listeners.

If you load this before any of the components, you will create a computed(reactive) variable available to any script on the page (frames and shadow dom aside)

then you can use in your components like this.

```html
<template>
  <aside :class="`${is_expanded ? 'is-expanded' : ''}`">
    <div class="head-aside">
      <div class="app-logo">
        <i class="bx bxl-trip-advisor"></i>
      </div>
      <span class="app-name">CONTROLPANEL</span>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-toggle-wrap">
      <button class="menu-toggle" @click="is_expanded = !is_expanded">
        <span class="boxicons"><i class="bx bx-chevrons-right"></i></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </aside>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      is_expanded: window.IS_EXPANDED,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

because `is_expanded` is a computed with with getters and setters, you can set the value straight from the template, or use `this.is_expanded = !this.is_expanded` in methods.

As stated already, this relies on using the global `window` object. This solution is proposed for its simplicity. There are some drawbacks to using the window object, and a more robust solution would rely on injecting such shared state instead of relying on window, but it comes with more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine

```html
<template>
  <aside :class="`${is_expanded ? 'is-expanded' : ''}`">
    <div class="head-aside">
      <div class="app-logo">
        <i class="bx bxl-trip-advisor"></i>
      </div>
      <span class="app-name">CONTROLPANEL</span>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-toggle-wrap">
      <button class="menu-toggle" @click="ToggleMenu()">
        <span class="boxicons">
          <i class="bx bx-chevrons-right"></i>click me
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </aside>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      is_expanded: localStorage.getItem("is_expanded") === "true",
    };
  },

  methods: {
    ToggleMenu() {
      this.is_expanded = !this.is_expanded;
      localStorage.setItem("is_expanded", this.is_expanded);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Here is a GIF showing the result in action: https://share.cleanshot.com/TtKsUj

Comment: hey,

yes this code work fine but in another component i have navbar with fixed width and i want to toggle his width at the same time

Comment: as you can see on this gif https://imgflip.com/gif/6wsrli

Comment: @furaxsme watching some localStorage is a bit more tricky overall. I guess that you could [use this](https://thewebdev.info/2022/03/11/how-to-watch-for-local-storage-changes-in-vue-js/) or [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74006100/vue-js-show-and-hide-the-navbar-on-different-pages-of-the-routing#comment130671743_74006100) (a bit more advanced) but there is no friendly way to access it since it's not reactive by itself. But then, do you even need it here? You could have a higher state or even use a store (Vuex, Pinia) to handle a global state aka replacing your localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Make local storage reactive  by using watcher and setting its deep property to true
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers
or if you are using vue2 then use event bus

Comment: A watcher can watch only a reactive prop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using Vue 3 composition API

```
let isOpen = ref(localStorage.getItem('is_open') === 'true');

const openMenu = () => {
            isOpen.value = !isOpen.value
            localStorage.setItem('is_open', isOpen.value);
     }

<aside id="logo-sidebar" :class="isOpen ? 'w-24 collapsed' : 'w-64' ">
```